# Why do I have two blue and two red wires in my ceiling light fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I want to replace a lighting fixture in the bathroom ceiling. I think it was kind of heat light. I took the light out and realized that two blue cables are connected to the fixture and two red ones on the other side and there is no neutral. What do I need to do to connect to live and neutral to install a halo ceiling light box and light?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help to know your location and voltage, I am guessing the other side of the Pond from the US and am reversing the down vote, that I think came from some on my side of the pond that don’t have a clue.  I think it depends on the year built also but blue red might be neutral / hot 240v in some areas, give us a bit more info and we probably can help.

Comment: Can you find a make/model number label on the fixture? I think this is an integral-ballast CFL can, but am not certain...

Comment: The "EnergyStar" sticker might point at a USA location, but I've seen internationally produced items with brown/blue wiring for Hot/Neutral on 120V (which is standard euro-market hot/neutral for 230V, AFAIK). - but 3PE is right, that does look like a CFL socket.

Comment: It’s the USA. I will look tomorrow for the make/model.

Comment: Thank you for including pics! It appears, though, that you accidentally shared the same image for the 2nd and 3rd pics. Please [edit] to remove one and share the proper 3rd image (if you have one).

Comment: I will go with an electrician for help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### This appears to be a CFL can with an integral ballast

What you are looking at appears to be a type of recessed "can" downlight that was designed to use a 4-pin compact fluorescent bulb with the ballast for that bulb integrated into the fixture.  (Think of a "tube" style fluorescent fixture that's been zapped with a twisty shrink ray.)

As a result, if you want to do something other than put a CFL in it, you'll need to replace the fixture outright (or have the electrician put a replacement in for you).